# A derivation of the Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

The [generating function for the Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function) $B_n$ is
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$$

The [sum of an infinite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) is
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$

Replacing $x$ with $e^x$ yields
$$\frac{1}{1-e^x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(e^x)^k$$

Multiplying both sides by $-x$ yields
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty(e^x)^kx$$

Hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(e^x)^kx+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n=0$$

Replacing $x$ with the derivative operator $D$ yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(e^D)^kD+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}D^n=0$$

The [exponential of the derivative operator is the shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Functions_of_a_real_variable) $T$:
$$e^D=T$$

Hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty T^kD+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}D^n=0$$

Applying this to a function $f$ yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (T^kDf)(x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}(D^nf)(x)=0$$

which is equivalent by $(Tf)(x)=f(x+1)$ to
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (Df)(x+k)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}(D^nf)(x)=0$$

If $Df=g$, this means
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(x+k)+\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}(D^ng)(x)=0$$

Since the values of the [Riemann zeta function at the negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) are
$$\zeta(-n)=-\frac{B_{n+1}}{(n+1)}$$

This can be expressed as
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(x+k)+\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(-n)}{n!}(D^ng)(x)=0$$

or
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(x+k)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(-n)}{n!}(D^ng)(x)-\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Have I derived a version of the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) correctly? Is an additional error term needed somewhere? Why does the expression on the right side of the equation seem to depend on $a$, while the one on the left does not?

How can I manipulate this procedure to obtain the more traditional version of the formula, e.g. with finite sums? I know, for example, that one can express a finite sum of powers using

$$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$$

Comment: As one can expect, the justification for the operatorial manipulations is choosing a suitable function space (essentially, analytic with limited growth) where these operators act upon, then convergence is made formal using the operator norm, etc.
I've found a detailed proof [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39197533.pdf).

Also: 1. The $a$ in the rhs reflects the fact $D^{-1}$ is not well-defined. 2. You can indeed get the finite sum using the partial sum of the geometric series, same for the remainder term.