# Closed form for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, lambert-w

Apologies if this has been asked before. I am wondering if the following [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) has a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression):

> $$\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2}\tag{1}$$

where $W(x)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). I am interested in this series as an extension of [the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln{n^2}}{n^2}=-2\zeta'(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}\ln{\left(\frac{A^{12}}{2\pi e^\gamma}\right)}\tag{2}$$

since $W(x)$ is the product logarithm. Obviously $(1)$ must converge by [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with $(2)$ since $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$ so $W(x)e^{W(x)}<\ln(x)e^{\ln{x}}$ so $W(x)<\ln{x}$ for $x\ge1$ by monotonicity of $W(x)$. However, I am not sure what it converges to. A value (obtained by a couple of toy formal methods) is $\alpha\overset{!}{=}\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$, but I do not think this is an  equality (although it is hard to tell since the series converges so slowly). Using Wolfram Alpha to sum to $10000$ terms, the partial sum [appears to be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%3D1%20to%2010000%20lambertw(n%5E2)%2Fn%5E2) $2.0142453>2.0066283=\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$, but I do not know $\alpha$'s exact numerical value.

Thus my **question** is: Is there a closed form for $\alpha$? If not, is there an expression for the error in the $\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$ approximation?

---

**My attempts**: *(Note: I have only put the following here to show where I got the value of $\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$ from; I assume that the methods are not properly correct)*. In the first place, using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988553/criteria-for-formally-derived-euler-maclaurin-type-formula) toy resummation formula I had derived, the formula $\int_0^\infty\frac{W(x^2)}{x^2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$ (derivable from [$\int_0^\infty\frac{W(x)}{x\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{8\pi}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Definite_integrals)) and the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) of $W(x)$ I formally calculated $\alpha=\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$. However, the given resummation formula often gives the wrong answer.

I also attempted to evaluate the integral using the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) (although I do not think $\frac{W(z^2)}{z^2}$ satisfies the conditions to apply it). Formally using the fact that $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{W(s^2)}{s^2}=1$, I got:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2}=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{W(x^2)}{x^2}\;dx-\frac{1}{2}+i\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{W(-t^2)}{-t^2}-\frac{W(-t^2)}{-t^2}}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\;dt=\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$$

I assume that the occurrences of this incorrect value are to do with my incorrect applications of these rules missing some remainder term, but I do not know a good way of rectifying this. So my question is: does anyone know a way of evaluating $(*)$ exactly?

Comment: What makes you think this *has* as closed form??

Comment: This is a really strange question, but a closed form might exist. For instance, $\frac{W(n)}{n^2}$ is the residue at $z=W(n)$ of $\frac{\pi(1+z)\cot(\pi z e^z)}{z e^z}$. However, I do not think the hypothesis of EMC or Abel-Plana are met, and numerically $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2}$ is a bit larger than $\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$, even if not by much.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I don't know that it does, but I'm wondering because it was easy to attack by the methods I tried (since the corresponding infinite integral is easy), but which seemed to give the wrong answer. Because of this I was wondering whether there was a better way to approach it which would give a result. I was also led to speculate by comparison with the series involving the usual logarithm, since I know that $W(x)$ sometimes does lend itself to fairly simple analyses due to its definition. I have been wondering about the value of this series for quite a long time now.

Comment: The issue is that $W(z^2)/z^2$ has branch cut along the imaginary axis. I guess that resolving this branch-cut issue yields $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2} = \sqrt{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2} + 2 \int_{1/\sqrt{e}}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Im}W(-t^2+i 0^+)}{(e^{2\pi t} - 1) t^2} \, dt. $$ Mathematica 11 seems to be agreeing with this claim that both sides give approx. values $2.016001\cdots$.

Comment: Running millions of summations through mathematica gives an answer of about $2.016$

Comment: @SangchulLee The integral looks quite evil.

Comment: @SangchulLee nice observation. Any idea *how* to integrate such a beast?

Comment: It just seems to me a pure evil. :s

Comment: @SangchulLee: is, by chance, $\text{Im}W(-t^2)$ bounded by $\pi$ for $t>\exp(-1/2)$? This would lead to a reasonable approximation of the error term.

Comment: @SangchulLee: I have to check. I said that because I thought that the most reasonable way for solving $xe^x=-M$ is to apply Newton's method with starting point $x=\frac{\log M}{\log\log M}+\pi i$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I take my word back. Honestly I have no idea, but now I am more convinced that it is bounded by $\pi$.

Comment: Me too, but a better starting point should be $\log M-\log\log M+\pi i$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, It seems to me that $f(z) = ze^z$ maps $$\mathcal{D} = \{x+iy \in \Bbb{C} : y \in (-\pi, \pi) \text{ and } x > -y \cot y \}$$ injectively onto $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, -e^{-1}]$. That is, $W$ is a map $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, -e^{-1}] \to \mathcal{D}$.

Comment: You sure line $(2)$ shouldn't read $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n^2)}{n^2}=-2\zeta'(2)?$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's certainly what I meant, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't know if can be useful, but note that from a direct application of the Mellin transform it is possible to prove that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{W(n^{2})}{n^{2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(2s+2)(-s)^{-s}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{s}ds$$ where $c<-1.$

Comment: @MarcoCantarini I'm not sure exactly how you proved it, but it looks interesting. I'm not sure where to go from that though... It seems vaguely similar to the form of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_master_theorem).

Comment: @Anon I used a property of the Mellin transform. If you want I can write my calculations. Note that the integral doesn't vanish when $c \rightarrow - \infty$ and for this reason the closed form is not only $\sqrt{2 \pi}-\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Thank you, that's alright. I can't really see a nice way of evaluating that integral anyway, although it is a nice way of writing the error term.

Comment: Maybe [Poisson summation formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonSumFormula.html) works, but also [this $W(x)$ series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lambertw%2833%29%2Cln%2833.0%29%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5Em%2Fm%21+ln%2833%29%5E%281-m%29+pochhammer%28m-k%2B1%2Ck%29+StirlingS1%28m-1%2Ck%29+ln%28ln%2833%29%29%5E%28m-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C19%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C19%7D%5D) gives you a series of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^{m-k}(2\ln(n))}{\ln^{m-1}(n)n^2}$. This $n$ sum can [use Stirling numbers](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/) to evaluate it.

Answer (score 4):

*Just a few numbers*

Computing
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\frac{W\left(n^2\right)}{n^2}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & S_k \\
 3 & 2.00276605784206527342788 \\
 4 & 2.01424531490397345666972 \\
 5 & 2.01578185484283675359672 \\
 6 & 2.01597490197032815619980 \\
 7 & 2.01599818252359384501875 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The last value seems to be quite close to
$$\frac{1}{\gamma }\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}=S_7+3.775\times 10^{-9}$$