# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname W(e^{e^{an}})x^n$ with Lambert W function

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, lambert-w, stirling-numbers, polylogarithm

$\def\W{\operatorname W} \def\Li{\operatorname{Li}} $

Interested by [$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{\W(n^2)}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134316/closed-form-for-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracwn2n2), here is an example where [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) applies to a [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) sum:

> $$\W(x)=\ln(x)+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m(m-k+1)_kS_{m-1}^{(k)}}{\ln^{m-1}(x)m!}\ln^{m-k}(\ln(x))$$

for about $|x|>e$ with the [Pochhammer symbol $n^{(m)}$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and [Stirling S1 $S_n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS1.html). Therefore the [polylogarithm](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/) appears:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\W(e^{e^{an}})x^n=1+\frac1{1-e^ax} +\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}(m-k+1)_kS_{m-1}^{(k)}a^{m-k}\Li_{k-m}(e^{(a-1)m}x),a>0$$

[Expanding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130184/polylogarithms-of-negative-integer-order) the polylogarithm uses [Stirling S2 $s_n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2.html):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\W(e^{e^{an}})x^n= 1+\frac1{1-e^ax}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{m-k+1}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}a^{m-k}(m-k+1)_k \Gamma(j) S_{m-1}^{(k)}s_{m-k+1}^{(j)}\left(\frac x{e^{(m-1)a}-x}\right)^j$$

Even the [$S_n^{(m)}$ limit expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/06/03/) does not help evaluate the sum over $m$ or $k$, but this method numerically [works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2B1%2F%28e+-+1%29%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5B+j%21+stirlings2%28m-k%2B1%2Cj%2B1%29+%28e%5E%281%2Bm%29-1%29%5E%28-j-1%29+%28-1%29%5Em%2Fm%21+pochhammer%28m-k%2B1%2Ck%29+StirlingS1%28m-1%2Ck%29%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C20%7D%5D-sum%5Blambertw%28e%5Ee%5En%29+e%5E%28-2+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C20%7D%5D).

How can one evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\W(e^{e^{an}})x^n$?

Comment: $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{W(n^2)}{n^2}$ *seems* to be (at least very close to) $\sqrt{2} \zeta (5)-\log (\gamma )$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That sum is in the linked question. Do you have a hint for the one in this question?

Comment: I do not "see" where is the linked question. Could you give me the link in a comment  (in order I just click - remember that I am blind) ? By the way, fascinating problem !

Comment: [Link to linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134316/closed-form-for-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracwn2n2)

Comment: I got it. Thanks !

Comment: I added some numbers in the linked question. Cheers :-)